# Record type change through Javascript

Tags: javascript, record-type, ajax-toolkit

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

var orderObj = new sforce.SObject("Order__c"); 

var recType = sforce.connection.query("SELECT name,Id from RecordType where developername = 'OR_Open'");
alert(recType);
var records = recType.getArray("records");
alert(records);
orderObj.RecordTypeId = records[0].Id;
alert(records[0].id);
sforce.connection.update([orderObj]);

window.location.reload();

}
```

I am getting undefined in  alert(records[0].id);. Please suggest where am i wrong?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add what are you getting for `alert(recType);` and `alert(records);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Apex, JavaScript is case-sensitive so `id` is different to `Id`.

You need to use `records[0].Id` in your alert, rather than `records[0].id`.